# Does accessing a methods returned value re-run the method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, methods

As I am learning Python, and programming in general, I've come across a concept I'm not very sure of. I am working on a script and I am curious on if I have already created object and if I want to access the returned value from one of that object's methods, will it rerun the method, or will it simply reply back with those values. For example:

```
class ClassOne():
    def oneMethod(self):
        x = 2
        y = 10
        return x, y

class ClassTwo():
    def twoMethod(self, x, y):
        ...

newObject = ClassOne()
newObject.oneMethod()

secondObject = ClassTwo()

# My question is, will the lines below re-execute newObject.oneMethod()
# or will it simply pull the already returned value

secondObject.twoMethod(newObject.oneMethod()[0],
                       newObject.oneMethod()[1])
```

While my script isn't necessarily large enough to be super worried about performance, it's just something I'm wondering and couldn't find much info about online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your title asks a different question from the text body.

No, accessing the result of a method won't rerun the method. But that's not what you're doing here; you explicitly call the method twice, so of course it will run twice.

The normal thing to do is to assign the returned value to a variable and use that as many times as you want.

Comment: Thanks for the response! On your last point, where would you typjcally define that variable and what would it look like? Thanks!

Comment: @Neemaximo You would do something like `coords = newObject.oneMethod()` on the line before the `twoMethod` call, which you would change to read `secondObject.twoMethod(coords[0], coords[1])`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, the method will re-execute each time it is called.

You could verify that by adding a call to `print()` in `oneMethod()` to see whether its code is executed every time it is called. You will find that it is.

You can avoid re-execution by binding the return value to some variable(s), e.g.

```
a, b = newObject.oneMethod()    # will call and execute the code in oneMethod()
secondObject = ClassTwo()
secondObject.twoMethod(a, b)
```

Here the tuple `(2, 10)` will be returned from `oneMethod()` and it will be unpacked into the variables `a` and `b` such that `a = 2` and `b = 10`. You could also use a single tuple variable, and then access individual elements via indexing:

```
t = newObject.oneMethod()
secondObject.twoMethod(t[0], t[1])
# secondObject.twoMethod(*t)    # also works, see below...
```

Another way, without having to save the return value first, is to pass the return value of `oneMethod()` directly into `twoMethod()` using tuple unpacking with the `*` operator:

```
secondObject = ClassTwo()
secondObject.twoMethod(*newObject.oneMethod())
```